# Open a local xml file using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I'm trying to open a .xml storared on my own PC using javascript and do some stuff,just for knowledge, in order to do that, I've
found a example on site
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_xmlfile.asp which uses AJAX and the object XMLHttpRequest, but, it does not work like the example showed in the site, I understand that the problem is that AJAX uses a server, so, I wonder if there is another solution to do that without a server, I just want to work with the file on my own pc or on a shared network like for example when we uses a shared workbook on excel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The security model for Javascript in browsers does not allow you to open local files. If you are wanting to do something like this using Javascript, you would need to look into installing something that runs outside the browser like Node.js.

https://nodejs.org/